# c# load data from txt file to combo box and get second value

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to the second value of every line. Example:

```
Joshua,Kind,12
John,Amazing,85
Farrah,Smart,81
```

And combo box will displayed

```
 - Kind
 - Amazing
 - Smart
```

My code:

```
    string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1\Desktop\2.txt");
    foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
    {
        string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
        comboBox1.Items.Add(tokens[0]);
    }
```

I'm getting the first value. So i try this one:

```
    string[] tokens = line.Split(',')[1];
```

But im getting an error. How can i display the second value of every line in combobox? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using directly the indexer on the returning value of Split means that the result is no more an array but directly a string

You could write

```
string token = line.Split(',')[1];
```

or

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(line.Split(',')[1]);
```

However this code is very dangerous. What happen if, for whatever reason, a line in your textfile cannot be correctly splitted in 3 parts? I would prefer to be safe and protect the loop from unwanted out of range exceptions with this

```
string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1\Desktop\2.txt");
foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
{
    string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
    if(tokens.Length >= 2)
       comboBox1.Items.Add(tokens[1]);
}
```

Comment: Rule #1 never trust your inputs.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Remember to upvote the answers that you find helpful and accept at least one if it resolves your problem

Answer (score 0):

don't change (it's correct):

```
string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
```

just change:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(tokens[0]);
```

to (change the 0 to 1 so you get the 2nd element rather than the 1st):

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(tokens[1]);
```

complete code:

```
string[] lineOfContents = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\1\Desktop\2.txt");
foreach (var line in lineOfContents)
{
    string[] tokens = line.Split(',');
    // get the 2nd element (the 1st item is always item 0)
    comboBox1.Items.Add(tokens[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(tokens[0]);
```

to this:

```
comboBox1.Items.Add(tokens[1]);
```

that because your token array contains three elements after split (at indexes 0, 1, 2);

If you want to use second approach:

just change: `string[] tokens = line.Split(',')[1];` to `string tokens = line.Split(',')[1];`

when using indexer directly just value is returned not array.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is that you have to change

> string[] tokens = line.Split(',')[1];

with

> string tokens = line.Split(',')[1];

as you are reading just one element (the second one)

Cheers.